# Shared CUDA job server

Tags: server, cuda, shared-folders, automation, job-control

I am using 16.04 to run my CUDA projects, all is working well.

The way that I currently use the server is to transfer files to the server and SSH in to run the code and view the output, which is okay when its just me, but is becoming more of a hassle now that more people want to use it.

I would like a solution where there a system where users could upload their jobs, and the output would be piped back to them.

Could anyone provide pointers to any services/scripts/examples that I could have a look at?

Any help is appreciated,

Tom

Edit: in response to a comment, I want to add that I am not looking for concurrent use of the GPU, rather a queue of jobs that would run sequentially. Sorry for not putting this in the original post!

Comment: Did you Google "Is cuda multitasking safe?" because what you are trying to do has many problems, like busy cpu loops waiting for a free GPU slot, etc.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I do not want concurrent use of the GPU, simply a queue of jobs that run sequentially.

Comment: Did you look at xjobs?  Used with a named pipe, sounds pretty much like what you want.